My React app won't render after upgrading to Node 22
I just upgraded from Node 14 --> 22. I'm trying to build my app but keep running into problems. After upgrading Node, I was able to successfully build and run my app from a feature branch but when I switched back to develop I continued to have problems.
I believe this has something to do with mismatched versions of React and my build/linking process. I've listed out my versions of react and react-dom but nothing looks off. I've also defined react and react-dom as peer dependencies. I've repeated the below process multiple times but still get the same result.
My app builds and runs without errors but when I run "npm run start" I see the following.
Console Error 1:
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Console Error 2:
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
The page is also blank.
Repo Structure:
|----project-root
|----packages/react
        |----node_modules
        |----package.json
        |----package-lock.json
|----node_modules
|----package.json
|----package-lock.json

I'm using roll-up to build the app.
My steps:
1. Switched to node 22 w/NVM
2. npm cache clean --force from the root
3. Deleted node_modules and pack-lock.json files in both root and packages/react   
4. Ran npm i from root
5. Ran npm run build-lib from packages/react 
6. Ran npm link from packages/react 
7. Ran npm link @root-app from root
8. Ran npm run start  

Usually I get an error here.
Then I followed these commands.
1. Deleted node_modules from the root again.
2. Running npm prune
3. Ran the linking commands again.

After following all of this, my app WORKED when I tried it from my feature branch. But when I switched back to develop and repeated the process, I'm still getting errors.

Rememebr to show the error(s) you get by copy-pasting them with code formatting, including the stack trace, and be explicit about where you see them, because browser errors are a completely different thing from Node errors. And also remember to say which version of React you're using: Node 14 has been dead for a long time now, and supported a wide range of also now-dead versions of React, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong without specific version information. That said: why do you have a packages/react dir at all? Just manage that normally?
